# Integrate workflow Jbpm in ofbiz

Tags: workflow, jbpm, ofbiz

i want to intergate workflow jbpm into ofbiz but i have no idea to how i ca do that, i ask  if any one have any idea thanks

```
<definitions id="Definition"
         targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/MinimalExample"
         typeLanguage="http://www.java.com/javaTypes"
         expressionLanguage="http://www.mvel.org/2.0"
         xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xs:schemaLocation="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL BPMN20.xsd"
         xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI"
         xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC"
         xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI"
         xmlns:tns="http://www.jboss.org/drools">
```

```
<!-- nodes -->
<startEvent id="_1" name="StartProcess" />
<scriptTask id="_2" name="Hello" >
  <script>System.out.println("Hello World");</script>
</scriptTask>
<endEvent id="_3" name="EndProcess" >
    <terminateEventDefinition/>
</endEvent>

<!-- connections -->
<sequenceFlow id="_1-_2" sourceRef="_1" targetRef="_2" />
<sequenceFlow id="_2-_3" sourceRef="_2" targetRef="_3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

OFBiz has abandonned using workflow engines, and rather uses an [Event Driven Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture)

You should rather use [the OFBiz user ML](http://ofbiz.apache.org/mailing-lists.html) for such questions, see for instance http://markmail.org/message/6q3jodp72idcbt6u

Nevertheless you might be interested by http://markmail.org/message/5scudisocmhljwqi

HTH

Comment: Not OOTB but will very old versions. You may ask Hans Bakker about https://www.activiti.org/, see link above